# Accessing values in json using python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON string as below

```
typ_json="{'FromPort': 80, 'IpProtocol': 'tcp', 'IpRanges': [{'CidrIp': '0.0.0.0/0'}], 'Ipv6Ranges': [{'CidrIpv6': '::/0'}], 'PrefixListIds': [], 'ToPort': 80, 'UserIdGroupPairs': []}"
```

I want to access `FromPort` and `ToPort` Values.

I have tried `print(typ_json['FromPort'])`

But I get the error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: I'd also recommend that you use `typ_json.get(key)` instead of directly accessing the key, as it might not exist.

Comment: That's not valid JSON.  It looks like a Python dictionary converted to `str`.

Comment: The question and the error is misleading. `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` suggests it is a `list`, but what you showed is a `str`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to convert the `json` to `dictionary`

```
import json
data = json.loads(typ_json)
print(data['FromPort'])
```

Sometimes `json` might give some error. In that case you can use `ast.literal_eval`

```
import ast
data = ast.literal_eval(typ_json)
print(data['FromPort'])
```

Answer (score 0):

That is `not` valid `JSON`. You need to replace the `quotes` and `load` the resulting `str`ing  like,

```
>>> import json
>>> typ_json
"{'FromPort': 80, 'IpProtocol': 'tcp', 'IpRanges': [{'CidrIp': '0.0.0.0/0'}], 'Ipv6Ranges': [{'CidrIpv6': '::/0'}], 'PrefixListIds': [], 'ToPort': 80, 'UserIdGroupPairs': []}"
>>> x = typ_json.replace("'", '"')
>>> json.loads(x) # now it is a `dict` and you can access the values
{u'PrefixListIds': [], u'FromPort': 80, u'IpRanges': [{u'CidrIp': u'0.0.0.0/0'}], u'ToPort': 80, u'IpProtocol': u'tcp', u'UserIdGroupPairs': [], u'Ipv6Ranges': [{u'CidrIpv6': u'::/0'}]}
>>> json.loads(x)['FromPort']
80
```

Comment: I get this error   AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: Then your `typ_json` was already a `dict` then. But what you showed in the question, suggested it was an `str`

Comment: Assuming it is already a dict how can i access FromPort Value?

Comment: `typ_json['FromPort']` will give you that

Answer (score -1):

```
import json
import ast

typ_json="{'FromPort': 80, 'IpProtocol': 'tcp', 'IpRanges': [{'CidrIp': '0.0.0.0/0'}], 'Ipv6Ranges': [{'CidrIpv6': '::/0'}], 'PrefixListIds': [], 'ToPort': 80, 'UserIdGroupPairs': []}"

port = ast.literal_eval(typ_json)
print(port['FromPort'])
```

Comment: how is this different from the other answer?

Comment: I didn't see your answer, so I thought it should be the right answer.